# Only clients whose minimum Enrollment is tied to a service

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssrs-2012

Hi all I looking to write a query that returns a data set showing only clients whose first enrollment has a servicetype 'Orientation'
Example data below

```
client clientID  enrollment date  enrollmentID           service date  serviceID        service type
  sam    01         03-04-2018      1005                    03-04-2018    3005             search
  sam    01         02-03-2018      1004                    02-03-2018    3004          orientation
  jon    02         7-05-2017       1003                    1-04-2017     3003          Search other
  jon    02         1-04-2017       1002                    1-05-2017     3002           orientation
  sam    01         1-02-2017       1001                    1-05-2017     3001            search

The desired result set is
jon    02         1-04-2017       1002                    1-05-2017     3002           orientation
```

Comment: what's wrong with `WHERE [service type] = 'orientation'` ?

Comment: so that also pulls in sam to the report. You see his earliest enrollment is not tied to orientation.

Comment: @HenryAmadi Are your dates in month-day-year format?  Because if they are day-month-year, then both Sam and Jon have their earliest enrollment record as orientation.

Comment: oh no its mmddyyyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here to target the first enrollment records for each client.  Then, we can additionally assert that the service type was `orientation`:

```
SELECT client, clientID, [enrollment date], enrollmentID, [service date],
    serviceID, [service type]
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientID ORDER BY [enrollment date]) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND [service type] = 'orientation';
```

Comment: This looks good, let me give it a shot but I tried row number and it didn't work maybe i didn't define properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use window function row-number()

```
select * from 
(select client, clientID,  enrollmentdate,  enrollmentID ,servicedate,serviceID,servicetype,row_number() over(order by enrollmentdate) rownum
from tablename where servicetype='orientation')a where rownum=1
```

OR you can use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename t1 where enrollmentdate in (select min(enrollmentdate) from tablename t2)
where servicetype='orientation'
```